# system.OutOfMemoryException in UFT 12.01

Tags: vbscript

I have 46 XML files in a folder. I have to read all these files and add some column information in them.

I have written this script:

```
Dim fso,f
Set fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set f=fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\XML FILES\songs\13102276_20140906")
Set xmlObj = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
For each x in f.Files
    filename = x
    print filename
    wait (5)
    xmlObj.LoadFile(filename)
    wait 1
    Allduration=chargessummary("/SUBCUSTBRK/ITEMIZED/TRANSACTION/CALL_TYPES/DATA/R/C29")
    print "Allduration" & "=" & Allduration
    set xmlObj = nothing
Next
function chargessummary(path)
    Set charges = xmlObj.ChildElementsByPath(path)
    sum = 0 
    For i = 1 to charges.Count
        'Print "pstn c6 " & i &"=" &  pstncharges.Item(i).Value()
        sum = sum + charges.Item(i).Value()

    Next
    chargessummary = sum

End function
```

However, this error is being shown:

> system.OutOfMemoryException

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the error message, but you should move the `Set xmlObj = XMLUtil.CreateXML()` to _inside_ of the `for each` loop, because on the 2nd file, `xmlObj` will be `Nothing` and you will get an error trying to call `LoadFile()`.

Comment: How big are your XML files?

Comment: even i tried it by keeping Set xmlObj = XMLUtil.CreateXML() inside the foreach loop.but i am getting the same error.and all my 46 xml files size is around 3.5GB.

Comment: @shivajumar 3.5GB each? It might be better to make this script run for a single file and then run it for each file in turn (eg from a batch file) - it will give the system a chance to  clear memory

Comment: Total 46 xml file size is 3.5GB..and even i tried it by calling indiviual xml files.but i am getting the same error.

Comment: do you get any other error information? such as line number? I have no experience of UFT so I don't think I can help you as it is probably system specific.

Comment: can any one slove it for me.i need it very urgently. Thanx in advance

Comment: Is there a method to free up/unload in QTP (other sites indicate a `xmlObj.Finalize` method)? If there is, replace `set xmlObj = nothing` with it. How far did you get before OutOfMemoryException?